# Python how to get values in one dataframe from the other dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape((5,5)),index=pd.date_range('2015/01/01',periods=5,freq='D')))  
df1['trading_signal']=[1,-1,1,-1,1]
```

df1

```
             0   1   2   3   4  trading_signal
2015-01-01   0   1   2   3   4         1
2015-01-02   5   6   7   8   9        -1
2015-01-03  10  11  12  13  14         1
2015-01-04  15  16  17  18  19        -1
2015-01-05  20  21  22  23  24         1
```

and
df2

```
                      0   1   2   3   4  
Date       Time                                        
2015-01-01 22:55:00   0   1   2   3   4             
           23:55:00   5   6   7   8   9               
2015-01-02 00:55:00  10  11  12  13  14               
           01:55:00  15  16  17  18  19               
           02:55:00  20  21  22  23  24
```

how would I get the value of trading_signal from df1 and sent it to df2.
I want an output like this:

```
                      0   1   2   3   4  trading_signal
Date       Time                                        
2015-01-01 22:55:00   0   1   2   3   4          1    
           23:55:00   5   6   7   8   9          1     
2015-01-02 00:55:00  10  11  12  13  14         -1     
           01:55:00  15  16  17  18  19         -1   
           02:55:00  20  21  22  23  24         -1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please edit the post to improve readability

Comment: Can you read your own post?

Comment: sorry...this is my first time to login SO...

Comment: Show the code you made so far

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.
Please note that, as this isn't a homework service, you need to show what you have tried (that's the missing part), and should provide a concrete example (you did that). 
Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I've made an exception and answered your question since it's the first time you're on stack overflow, but in the future if you don't provide a mcve and what you've tried so far, you likely won't get any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either merge or join. If you merge you need to reset_index, which is less memory efficient ans slower than using join. Please read the docs on [Joining a single index to a multi index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#joining-a-single-index-to-a-multi-index):

> New in version 0.14.0.
>
> You can join a singly-indexed DataFrame with a level of a
>   multi-indexed DataFrame. The level will match on the name of the index
>   of the singly-indexed frame against a level name of the multi-indexed
>   frame

If you want to use join, you must name the index of df1 to be `Date` so that it matches the name of the first level of `df2`:

```
df1.index.names = ['Date']
df1[['trading_signal']].join(df2, how='right')


                     trading_signal   0   1   2   3   4
Date       Time                                        
2015-01-01 22:55:00               1   0   1   2   3   4
           23:55:00               1   5   6   7   8   9
2015-01-02 00:55:00              -1  10  11  12  13  14
           01:55:00              -1  15  16  17  18  19
           02:55:00              -1  20  21  22  23  24
```

I'm joining right for a reason, if you don't understand what this means please read [Brief primer on merge methods (relational algebra)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra).